# python error setting array element with sequence

Tags: python, arrays, sequence

I am getting the message " setting an array element with a sequence." on xstar,ystar, zstar.  I know what it means but can't figure out where the problem is. I have calculated the x,y and z position of a star in a galaxy and am trying to insert that value into the  array for the x locations of all the stars.  you can see that I made what should be xstar equal to 'glen' and it forms one single float value, but when I try to insert it into the array, it gives me this error.

File "C:/Users/Glenn/.spyder-py3/Cluster.py", line 225, in setup
    xstar[k,i]=glen

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

This makes me think the problem is with my syntax on xstar[k,i], but I can't see what is wrong with that.  What is weird is that of k=0 the code seems to work, but when k=1 it goes to pot.
Here is the last few lines of a print out trying to figure out the problem:

0 9 14 158 34.0
xstar 109.73718069851107

0 9 15 159 34.0
xstar 100.04751534246702
1 0 0 0 5.0

below is the code. Any help would be appreciated. I am new to the language and have been stuck a couple of weeks here. sorry for the wrap around on the longer lines

```
import math
import numpy
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
import array
import random
import sys
...

xst = [[0.0 for i in range(1000)] for j in range(5)]
yst = [[0.0 for i in range(1000)] for j in range(5)]
zst = [[0.0 for i in range(1000)] for j in range(5)]


xstar = numpy.asarray(xst,numpy.float64,'C')
ystar = numpy.asarray(yst,numpy.float64,'C')
zstar = numpy.asarray(zst,numpy.float64,'C')



def setup():
    global dr
    global galnum
    global rings
    global star_per_ring
    global gc1
    global gc2
    global gc3
    global an
    global xstar
    global ystar
    global zstar

    for k in range(galnum-1):
        i=-1
        for ir in range(rings):    
            R=10+(ir-1)*dr
            if k==0:
                V=(M2[k]/R)**2
                th=(0.5*V/R)*(180/3.1415927)
                gc1 = 150
                gc2 = 100
                gc3 = 0
            else:

                V=(M2[k]/R)**0.5
                th=(0.5*V/R)*(180/3.1415927)
                gc1=150+x[k]-x[1]
                gc2=100+y[k]-y[1]       
                gc3=z[k]-z[1]        




            for it in range(star_per_ring):
                t=(it-1)*360
                t= t/star_per_ring
                fg=(it-1)*360/star_per_ring
                t1=3.1415927*(t-th)/180
                i=int(i+1)
                print(k, ir, it, i, an[k,0])
                glen = R*numpy.cos(t/57.2958)*numpy.cos(an[0,k])-\
                R*numpy.sin(t/57.2958)*numpy.sin(an[0,k])*numpy.cos(an[0,k])\
                +gc1;
                # print('glenn',glen, )
                xstar[k,i]=glen
                print('xstar',xstar[k,i])
                ystar[k,i] = R*numpy.cos(t/57.2958)*numpy.sin(an[1,k])+\
                R*numpy.cos(an[1,k])*numpy.sin(t/57.2958)*numpy.cos(an[0,k])\
                +gc2;
                zstar[k,i] = R*numpy.sin(t/57.2958)*numpy.sin(an[0,k])+gc3;
                vstarx = -V*numpy.sin(t1)*numpy.cos(an[1,k])-\
                V*numpy.cos(t1)*numpy.sin(an[1,k])*numpy.cos(an[1,k]);
                vstary = -V*numpy.sin(t1)*numpy.sin(an[1,k])\
                +V*numpy.cos(t1)*numpy.cos(an[1,k])*numpy.cos(an[1,k]);
                vstarz = V*numpy.cos(t1)*numpy.sin(an[0,k])
                if (k>1):
                    vstarx[k,i]=VX2[k]+vstarx[k,i]
                    vstary[k,i]=VY2[k]+vstary[k,i]
                    vstarz[k,i]=VZ2[k]+vstarz[k,i]
```

Answer (score 0):

is star a 2d array? if so then the way to call an object in a multi dimensional array is xstar[k][i].

Comment: Yes xstar, ystar and zstar are 2 d arrays. What this is is an attempt to model galaxy collisions and the xstar, ystar and zstar or the x, y and z locations for stars in 5 different galaxies.  I think I tried removing the indices from ystar to see what happened, but it doesn't work. If I can't fix it I will use a single 1d array for each galaxy